# Do I need to manually implement threading on the server side when implementing WCF callbacks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, callback

I have a WCF Singleton service with Attributes `[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]` that uses wsDualHttpBinding and allows the user to call in a database request.  These requests can be very long running and will often timeout.  I used the example given [here](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx) that I found in another answer on SO.  I have everything implemented and everything works correctly, however I am concerned about what will happen when multple clients attach to my service at the same time.  I have set the ConcurrencyMode to Multiple, but I'm not sure that will give me what I need.

My question is, do I have to create a new thread on the serverside each time a client calls in or does WCF handle that for me by hosting my OperationContracts in seperate threads?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WCF` will create the thread for every call from the client side.